# Which preposition to use: At Earth or On Earth?

Tags: prepositions

> We have Extreme temperatures on the Moon, but why do we not experience such extreme temperatures on the Earth? The reason is **at** Earth we have our atmosphere...

Is using "at" here correct? Or should I use "on"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"On Earth"

Using "at" implies that you imagine the Earth to be a single point (on some longer journey.  A space story may say "The rocket stopped at Earth to refuel, then continued on to Mars"

But that is not your situation.  The Earth is a big place, and you are on the surface of it.  Hence we normally say "on Earth".  In your particular situation I'd probably actually say "The reason is that Earth has an atmosphere"  That is simpler and more correct ("We" don't have an atmosphere, the Earth has an atmosphere.)

Comment: Thank for your answer... I provided a more complete sentence, I am comparing temperature of the celestial bodies... does it make more sense to use At?

Comment: No. See my proposed rephrasing that doesn't use on or at.

Comment: I just want to point out that this is an example of an OP re-asking the same question after it has been answered properly.

Answer (score 2):

You would say "on Earth". Also, in the first sentence you quoted, you would say "on Earth", not "on the Earth". Technically, you could say "on the Earth", but that would sound a little old-fashioned and formal.

Comment: Although in a piece contrasting different planets, as the comment on James K's answer reveals, 'on the Earth' makes sense as intensifying the comparison. (I use 'the Earth' myself, but I'm old, so...)